# Reading a file into R with partly unknown filename

Tags: r

Is there a way to read a file into R where I do not know the complete file name. Something like.

```
read.csv("abc_*")
```

In this case I do not know the complete file name after `abc_`

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is more than one file fulfilling your criteria?

Comment: @Thilo: There would be only one file with starting as abc. So, I would give initial abc and then want to use some search criteria like *

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have exactly one file matching your criteria, you can do it like this:

```
read.csv(dir(pattern='^abc_')[1])
```

If there is more than one file, this approach would just use the first hit. In a more elaborated version you could loop over all matches and append them to one dataframe or something like that.

Note that the pattern uses regular expressions and thus is a bit different from what you did expect (and what I wrongly assumed at my first shot to answer the question). Details can be found using `?regex`

---

If you have a directory you want to submit, you have do modify the `dir` command accordingly:

```
read.csv(dir('path/to/your/file', full.names=T, pattern="^abc"))
```

The submitted path in your case may be `c:\\users\\user\\desktop`, and then the pattern as above. `full.names=T` forces `dir()` to output a whole path and not only the file name. Try running `dir(...)` without the `read.csv` to understand what is happening there.

---

If you want to give your path as a complete string, it again gets a bit more complicated:

```
filepath <- 'path/to/your/file/abc_'
read.csv(dir(dirname(filepath), full.names=T, pattern=paste("^", basename(filepath), sep='')))
```

That process will fail if your filename contains any regular expression keywords. You would have to substitute then with their corresponding escape sequences upfront. But that again is another topic.

Comment: Note that `'abc_*'` does not match `abc_(wildcard)` but `abc(zero or more times _)`. Hence it will also match `abc.txt` or something like that.

Comment: Silly me. Of course you are right. Edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: I have tried the syntax as above. But I am getting an error.

read.csv(dir(pattern='c:\\users\\user\\desktop\\abc_*')[1])


Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory


I am not sure what am I doing wrong here....

Comment: @Kunal - did you try the edited version? If so, what is the error?

Comment: What I understand is that ^abc means abc can be in between as well. But, the file name which I have is abc_date. Now that date keeps changing obviously. So, I want abc_* like functionality. The above mentioned syntax suggested gave me an error which I have mentioned above.

Comment: @Kunal: Ah, you try to give a directory path as well. That, however, is a whole different topic. I will edit my answer accordingly. The `^abc` means that `abc` has to be the first three letters (`^` marks the beginning of the file name)

Comment: @Thilo: Ok.. Thnx for clarifying. Could you please consider the fact that I need to give complete directory path and suggest a way out.

Comment: @Kunal I edited my answer. Pleas try to state your whole requirements right at the start the next time.

Comment: @Thilo: It worked...Il make sure to mention all the conditions at the start.. Thnx a lot